# How to start a new custum project of Apereo CAS 5 : overlay or manal dependency

Tags: java, maven, single-sign-on, cas

I want to create a specific SSO server with CAS.

Specific because :

- graphical integration
- integrate particular CAS modules : pac4j, services manager, ...

I see 2 options :

- use cas-server-webapp overlay : it's fast and easy to use but overlay include a lot of stuff I don't want : angularJs, jquery, mongo dependancies, ...
- make my own webapp by assembling CAS modules with my depencies management (maven) : like the overlay but with just what I want.

What is the best way for start a new CAS server integration ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start a CAS deployment is by using the provided overlays. Exclude things you don't like, or build your own overlay.